# Duplicating elements in a list based on count vector

Tags: r, list

I have a list like the following:

`example <- list(c(1, 5, 3, 6, 3), c(4, 2, 56, 2, 56, 2), c(4, 2, 6,
       2, 6, 1, 34))`

And I would like to duplicate elements of the list based on this numeric vector:

`count <- c(5, 2, 1)`

I want a final output to be a list of length 8 (`sum(count)`) which has the first element of the list repeated 5 times, second element 2 times, and third element only once.

How would you do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, the base R function `rep()` should do what the OP expects:

```
rep(example, count)
```

> ```
> [[1]]
> [1] 1 5 3 6 3
>
> [[2]]
> [1] 1 5 3 6 3
>
> [[3]]
> [1] 1 5 3 6 3
>
> [[4]]
> [1] 1 5 3 6 3
>
> [[5]]
> [1] 1 5 3 6 3
>
> [[6]]
> [1]  4  2 56  2 56  2
>
> [[7]]
> [1]  4  2 56  2 56  2
>
> [[8]]
> [1]  4  2  6  2  6  1 34
> ```